# selenium click not working for a link in nasdaq site

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So the issue is very simple and straightforward. In the link
https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/iff/revenue-eps

I want to click the link "Previous 3 Years" using selenium, but it just doesnt seem to work.

The code below is what I attempted. It worked for most webpages, but not for this for some reason. I tried to find the element by the text it holds and click it.

```
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Previous 3 Years')
link.click()
```

And when I did eventually run it, this is the error message I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "writeTest.py", line 68, in <module>
    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Previous 3 Years')
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 428, in find_element_by_link_text
    return self.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Previous 3 Years"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=76.0.3809.100)
```

Can anyone please tell me what seems to be the issue here?

Comment: The link is inside frame, you need to switch to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Object is in `iframe` so you need to switch it You need To Write You code Like This

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#frmMain")))

link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Previous 3 Years')
link.click()
```

For Switching

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because targeted element is inside the `iframe`. That's why it can't be found, since you are working on the main content. Below code should work for you:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

revenue_table = driver.find_element(By.ID, value="frmMain")
driver.switch_to.frame(revenue_table)
# Your code
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Previous 3 Years')
link.click()

# You can switch back to the main content by below code:
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```